# Word Interop call to SaveCopyAs throws COMException "That method is not available on that object."

Tags: ms-word, com, vsto, office-interop

In the Office 2013 Primary Interop Assemblies, the Word interop assembly has a method [SaveCopyAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.savecopyas?view=word-pia).
(This method is not present in the Office 2010 PIAs.)

I need to call this method in a C# VSTO Word add-in, but it fails with a COMException "That method is not available on that object." (HRESULT = 0x800A1704).

I've tried it on a PC with Word 2013 installed, and on another (2) PCs with Word for Microsoft 365 installed, with the same result.

Context: A VSTO add-in has a button on a Word ribbon, and the onAction code for that button saves a copy of the current document to our document store. If the current Word document is opened from a folder, or already saved, I don't want to use SaveAs, as that will change the Path of the current document and disrupt subsequent Saves.

```
// (Add a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c)
var wordApplication = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
var document = wordApplication.ActiveDocument;
//document.GetType().Assembly.Dump(); // LINQPad
//System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(document.GetType().Assembly.Location).Dump(); // LINQPad
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(document.Path))
    document.SaveAs("Document must be saved first.docx");
document.SaveCopyAs("Document SaveCopyAs.docx"); // <- this throws
```

(In case versions matter) At the point of failure, document.GetType().Assembly is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c) and has FileVersion=15.0.4603.1000 (installed as part of Microsoft Office 365).

The exception:

```
Message: That method is not available on that object. 
InnerException: null 
TargetSite.RuntimeMethodInfo: DocumentClass.SaveCopyAs (Object& FileName, Object& FileFormat, Object& LockComments, Object& Password, Object& AddToRecentFiles, Object& WritePasswor... 
StackTrace: 
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentClass.SaveCopyAs(Object& FileName, Object& FileFormat, Object& LockComments, Object& Password, Object& AddToRecentFiles, Object& WritePassword, Object& ReadOnlyRecommended, Object& EmbedTrueTypeFonts, Object& SaveNativePictureFormat, Object& SaveFormsData, Object& SaveAsAOCELetter, Object& Encoding, Object& InsertLineBreaks, Object& AllowSubstitutions, Object& LineEnding, Object& AddBiDiMarks, Object& CompatibilityMode)
   at UserQuery 
HelpLink: wdmain11.chm#25372 
Source: Microsoft Word 
HResult: -2146822396
```

We currently use [IPersistFile.Save](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-ipersistfile-save) (rather than SaveCopyAs), which has been working well, except that if the original document has a password that was used to open it, the file that IPersistFile.Save() creates has the password removed, and I want the copy to still be password protected.
Also, Comments in the document get re-arranged slightly. I'm hoping that SaveCopyAs would fix those problems

Comment: We can't see the context of this code.  It would for example be troublesome to have it in an event handler for an Excel-generated event.

Comment: @HansPassant It is called from a button onAction handler.

Comment: @HansPassant

A button on a Word VSTO add-in ribbon looks like:

<customUI ... <ribbon> <tabs> <tab ... <button id="BtnSave" ... onAction="OnSaveClick"

The OnSaveClick method eventually calls document.SaveCopyAs(), as part of then uploading the resulting file.

However, Just those lines above will also fail with the same error when called in a LINQPad script, outside of the add-in

Comment: It looks like an error reported by Word, like it doesn't support calling that method at that time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477735/word-application-savecopyas-unknown-runtime-error-800a1704 (ie: not related to interop/com)

Comment: Is the workaround in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46947015/savecopyas-behavior-in-microsoft-word any use?

Comment: @jonsson We currently use IPersistFile, which has been working well, except that if the original document has a password that was used to open it, the file that IPersistFile.Save() creates has the password removed, and I want the copy to still be password protected.  
Also, Comments in the document get re-arranged slightly.  
I'm hoping that SaveCopyAs would fix those problems.

Comment: @SimonMourier It does look like Word doesn't support calling that method at any time, which would be a bug, since we have the most recent version of Word.  
(I can understand Word 2010 not supporting it, as that method is not in the 2010 PIAs.)

Comment: FWIW if I look for SaveCopyAs in the Object browser in Word VBE (in a current version of 365) it is a Hidden member. It only applies to the Document object. If I try to use it from VBA I get the same error message as you. I went back to a copy of Word 2013 and tried the same - it's also listed as a Hidden member and also does not work. Perhaps it has just never been implemented. I don't have a better suggestion on a workaround, sorry.